# Are TFS shelves a Diff related to a repository version or are they the entire files that were shelved?

Tags: tfs, shelve

Do `TFS` shelves have the entire files that were changed or do shelves have just the difference compared to a specific version of the repositotory? If it's the first than it can be applied in any version at any time. If it's the second, it can only be applied to a specific version of the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is exactly, since their internal representation should be an implementation detail.  But they're full files, stored as a change against the version they were modified from.

Beginning in TFS 2012, one can perform a 3-way merge on unshelve, using the shelved change's unmodified version as the common ancestor.